# Variable may not have been initizialized (java)

Tags: java

So I was trying to write a function for a ragged array; I may have got this entirely wrong, if so please explain why/how I went wrong. It took me ages to get this far and I have a feeling I've alreayd done it wrong.

I tried compiling it because I'm pretty sure currently it will work, however i'm getting the error "variable n may not have been initialized". My code so far is:

```
    static double[][] exampleMatrix()
    {
        int n;
        double[][] a = new double [3][];
        a[0] = new double[n-1];
        a[1] = new double[n];
        a[2] = new double[n-1];
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
            {
                a[0][i] = 1;
                a[2][i] = 1;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                a[1][i] = - i - 1;
            }
        return a;
        }
    }
```

I'm probably missing something really really obvious, but i'm not sure what it is to initialize n.

EDIT: I have been told to make this work for a value n that is not yet given.. How would I do that? As in, the user is supposed to input the value of n, and be given an array in return.

Basically, my given question is to implement a function exampleMatrix that, given n, produces the array where all values in teh array a[0] is 1, and same for a[2], and then for a[1], be given a range of values from -1 down to -n for a[1][n-1]. This is what I have so far to calculate this, but I am guessing I have gone completely wrong?

Comment: yeap, you do not seem to initialze `n` with anything.

Comment: Re your edit, what do you mean by not yet given? Do you mean not hard coded? (if so thats easy to solve) or that it is completely unknow to the computer (if so its impossible)

Answer (score 0):

Method variables (unlike fields) cannot rely on the default value (0 in this case). As such n is not anything when it is declared

```
int n;
```

You need to state what n is at some point between declaring it and using it, for example.

```
int n;
n=7;
```

or

```
int n=7;
```

### n not known at compile time

You can also pass n as a variable, if n is variable

```
static double[][] exampleMatrix(int n){
    double[][] a = new double [3][];
    a[0] = new double[n-1];
    a[1] = new double[n];
    a[2] = new double[n-1];
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        {
            a[0][i] = 1;
            a[2][i] = 1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            a[1][i] = - i - 1;
        }
    return a;
    }
}
```

This method would then be used as

```
double[][] someMatrix= exampleMatrix(5); //<-- 5 is passed into the function and becomes n
```

Or you can calculate n in whatever way you see fit

Comment: I have never seen the first line with something written within the brackets before, what exactly does that mean? Thank you so much for your help though.

Comment: @user3013480 you mean this `exampleMatrix(int n){`

Comment: Yes, the int n within the brackets there.

Comment: @user3013480 See my edit. But basically it allows you to pass variables into the function (there can be more than one)

Comment: @user3013480 No problem, I assume methods just became a lot more useful

Answer (score 0):

You don't set any value to `n`. How will your program know how big to make the arrays and how many iterations to run in the `for` loops?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Problem is with local variable

```
int n;
```

The scope of local variables is much narrower. Compiler knows when its getting used. Hence, forcing programmer to initialize the variable

You have to initialize it with any default value as `int n=0;`

Answer (score 0):

I want to complement the above responses.

You have to take care with the static segments, because when a class load its static segments, the class don't assign default value, if you type:

```
public static int n;
```

in your class, the value depends on the programmer. this can throw an exception about initialized.